# Include template at top level in Azure Pipeline YAML file

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

[The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#insert-a-template) suggests that there should be a way to take Azure Pipeline YAML templates and paste them into a different Azure Pipeline YAML file. However, I cannot find a way to do this at the top level. How do I do this?

To give a use-case, I have a YAML template called `deployment-environment.yml` that defines a deployment environment parameter and uses this parameter to decide the actual deployment environment. I want to include this in multiple pipelines (e.g. `azure-pipeline.yml` here) to avoid code duplication.

I am imagining something like the following in my main pipeline YAML file:

```
# azure-pipeline.yml
includes:
- template: deployment-environment.yml
```

With the following YAML template:

```
# deployment-environment.yml
parameters:
- name: deploymentEnvironmentSetting
  type: string
  default: auto
  values:
  - auto
  - none
  - dev
  - test
  - prod

variables:
- name: deploymentEnvironment
  ${{ if ne(parameters.deploymentEnvironmentSetting, 'auto') }}:
    value: ${{ parameters.deploymentEnvironmentSetting }}
  ${{ elseif eq(variables['Build.BuildSourceBranchName'], 'development') }}:
    value: dev
  ${{ elseif eq(variables['Build.BuildSourceBranchName'], 'test') }}:
    value: test
  ${{ elseif eq(variables['Build.BuildSourceBranchName'], 'main') }}:
    value: prod
  ${{ else }}:
    value: none
```

This is so that users may manually override the deployment environment using the Azure DevOps GUI, as shown in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdhru.png).

Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `includes` keyword in the pipeline schema. The documentation outlines that you can insert *templates* for **[Stage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#stage-reuse)**, **[Job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#job-reuse)** or **[Step](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#step-reuse)** reuse.

```
stages:
- template: stages.yml
```

```
jobs:
- template: deployment-job.yml
```

```
steps:
- template: download-pipeline-artifact-steps.yml
```

It helps to understand that there is a [schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/?view=azure-pipelines&tabs=schema,parameter-schema&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops) for azure-pipeline yaml and the `template` keyword is defined:

- [stages.template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/stages-template?view=azure-pipelines)
- [job.template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/jobs-template?view=azure-pipelines)
- [steps.template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/steps-template?view=azure-pipelines)
- [variables.template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/variables-template?view=azure-pipelines)

There is also an **[extends](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/extends?view=azure-pipelines)** keyword that allows you to describe the pipeline in one file and pass in arguments. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/extends?view=azure-pipelines) lists an example of doing what're describing above.

```
# File: start.yml
parameters:
- name: environmentName
  type: string
  default: auto

variables:
- ${{ if ne(parameters.environmentName, 'auto'):
  - name: environmentName
    value: ${{ parameters.environmentName }}

  ${{ elseif eq(variables['Build.BuildSourceBranchName'], 'development') }}:
  - name: environmentName
    value: dev

  ${{ elseif eq(variables['Build.BuildSourceBranchName'], 'test') }}:
  - name: environmentName
    value: test

  ${{ elseif eq(variables['Build.BuildSourceBranchName'], 'main') }}:
  - name: environmentName
    value: prod

  ${{ else }}:
  - name: environmentName
    value: none

stages:
- stage: build
  pool:
    vmImage: windows-latest
  jobs:
  - job: ci
    steps:
    - script: deploy to $(environmentName)
```

```
# pipeline.yml

trigger:
- main

parameters:
- name: deploymentEnvironmentSetting
  type: string
  default: auto
  values:
  - auto
  - none
  - dev
  - test
  - prod

extends:
  template: start.yml
  parameters:
     environment: ${{ parameters.deploymentEnvironmentSetting }}
```

Comment: I see. I believe in part the introduction to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/security/templates?view=azure-devops) had me a little confused. Thank you for suggesting an alternative solution.

Comment: Is there any way to let child template benefits the variable scope of the parent file ? So that we don't need to pass parameters... I thought that was the disctinction between `include` and `extend` templates, but apparently not.

Comment: @Mario - templates aren't like compiled script includes that are called like functions at runtime. Templates only exist at compile time: the system unravels and expands the templates out into one large file and then it is executed. Variables don't exist at compile time (except a limited set of system variables).  Variables only exist at runtime when they are _evaluated_.  So, yes, if you define a variable at a pipeline, stage or job level, it would be available inside or outside of a template. (see next comment)

Comment: part 2 - It is possible to define the default value of a parameter to be a variable `default: $(myVariable)`. This will allow you to reuse variables defined in previous scopes and only pass in the parameters you need.  But keep in mind that at compile-time this variable has no value, so it cannot be used in any compile-time conditional statements like `${{ if eq(variables['myVariable'], 'true') }}`.

Comment: @bryanbcook Tanks for the fast reply. Actually I had a ServiceConnectionName as variable, and Azure failed to authorize the ServiceConnection access when I called it like `$(ServiceConnectionName)` but it managed to make the auth validation when I called my variable like `${{ variables.ServiceConnectionName }}`. And that was before execution... So I guessed Azure is able to compute variable values at compile, before runtime. Am I wrong ? 


had a case where Azure was not able to perform authorization validation to let my pipeline access a Service Connection

Comment: Service-Connections are one of those things that must be known at compile-time, in order to get the correct approvals, etc.  User-defined variables _can_ be accessible at compile-time using the `${{ variables... }}` syntax, but there are constraints. I've had success when the variables are defined in the `pipeline.yml` and limited success when these variables are in templates. Definitely doesn't work for queue-time variables.

Comment: @bryanbcook part2. Also, that's not a pb for me if it's only at runtime as I'm not using compile-time statements.
I just expected that `include-templates` would "KNOW" the variables defined in the parent, without passing them as params. As it is in HELM templating for example (using `{{ include }}` tag). Especially if the system unravels and expands the templates into one large file... When you replace the `- template: my_template.yml` with the actual template, it should know the variables defined in `- variables:` right before the template call... Thanks for the default value tips though :)

Answer (score -1):

I have tested it a little and it seems that both 'just' inserting template and using keyword 'extends' does not propagate need of its parameters
to top level yaml file, so UI does not show Box for choosing one of them.

In my opinion unfortunatelly currently the only way to achieve it is to duplicate 'parameters' by adding keyword with allowed values
on top of azure-pipeline.yml, and then provided value should be passed to deployment-environment.yml.

[image]

Comment: In the screenshoot I have provided working version with parameters visible and customizable in UI(without using 'extends' keyword, just simple template call).

What is more, @bryanbcook is right that there is no keyword 'includes', you may have accidentally copied it from a code example.